# How to find the directrix in order to get intersection between two parabolas and a segment?

Tags: conic-sections, intersection-theory, voronoi-diagram

So I am trying to implement the Fortune's algorithm in order to have a Voronoi pattern (wonderful post about it here : http://www.ams.org/publicoutreach/feature-column/fcarc-voronoi)

For this, I need to know intersections between two parabolas, which I know how to do (thanks to this article : http://www.zonalandeducation.com/mmts/intersections/intersectionOfTwoParabollas1/intersectionOfTwoParabolas1.htm) but also something that the first article doesn't cover : how to find the value Y of the directrix when I want two parabolas to intersect in a specific X coordinate (while the two parabolas share the same directrix - 'the sweep line').

Let me explain better :
[See the image descripting the thing - As I am not allowed to have embed image yet :'(](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ItHpT.png)
The thing that the 1st article doesn't cover is that the edges between some sites infinitely continue to the left or to the right. What I want is to limit it into a plane (a square).
So, I have :

- A plane with its edges (I know the X and Y coordinates of its edges)
- Two focus points, f1 and f2 (for Fortune, those focus points are the sites), of the two parabolas, p1 and p2.
- A directrix (for Fortune, 'the sweep line') which is the same for all the focus points, and which I can move up and down as I want.

And I don't have the intersection between p1, p2 and the edges of the plane.

Actually, what I would like to have is the intersections circled in red here : https://i.stack.imgur.com/vp0Ql.jpg (I already have those in purple, thanks to the second article), but in order to get them, I need to find the Y-value of the directrix where two parabolas will intersect with the edge of the plane.

So, as shown in the image, how to find the Y value of the directrix, in order to get the intersection between p1, p2 and the left edge ?

Thank you for your time,

Cyril G

Answer (score 1):

This circled point $P$ is such that $d:=PF_1=PF_2=PH$ by definition of a parabola (same distance from a focus than to the directrix), you just have to take the directrix at vertical distance $d$ from $P$.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, however the thing (I don't explicitely said I agree, my bad) is that I don't know how to get the intersection P from p1, p2 and the left edge. Do you know how to do it ?

Comment: Point $P$ is at the intersection of line bissector of $F_1F_2$ with one of the parabolas.

Comment: Thank you, however, there is the problem : As you can see in this GIF https://imgur.com/a/DcL68py a parabola continously intersect an edge (starting when the directrix has reached the focus, ending when the focus is removed from the 'beachline' <- this concept is not important for our problem), so there is not only one intersection between the line and a parabola. I have to find the exact moment where p1 intersects p2 and intersects the line. Do you have an idea ? Thank you very much !

Comment: I have been looking at the (indeed excellent) description in the AMS document: apparently, you need to use the focci of **three** parabolas for finding $P$...

Comment: You are right, when it comes to find intersections in the 'inner side', which I solved thanks to the second article. But if you scroll all the way down, and see the image before 'Summary', you can see the edges built from the 'outside focus' continue infinitely. However, as you can in this image https://imgur.com/a/SY340Dk I would like to get the intersections circled in red (I already have those in purple), which are the intersections between two parabolas and a segment (the edge of a square). Thank you for reading about it and for your time !

Comment: Oh, maybe I have an idea : assuming the plane is not rotated (top and bottom edges parallel to X axis and left and right edges parallel to Y axis), maybe we can deduct a circle with center at X = left edge X and f1 and f2 being points of this circle. Then, like the AMS article said, the intersection is when a parabola disappears (ie. in our case, at the lowest point of this circle = the Y value of the directrix). I will try this out, you can always answer if you find a more 'mathematical' idea :) Thannk you !

Comment: I think you are on the right track. I have been programming this algorithm a long time ago and remember that it wasn't at all evident! Do you know that an alternative way to get a Voronoi tesselation is to derive it from the associated Delaunay triangulation (itself being now often derived from a convex hull algorithm, "Quickhull" family) ?

Comment: Yes I have heard about Delaunay triangulation and I saw that with one, you can have the other (as Delaunay and Voronoi are dual graphs). I actually plan to get Delaunay triangulation after I get the Voronoi diagram. I just wanted to use the Fortune's algortihm because seeing it in action is really pretty and kind of mesmerizing haha, but it's okay because I have learnt a lot ! Thank you for your time, I think I will achieve this soon !